# How to capture the "closest" group (regex)?

Tags: swift, regex, regex-group

I think best is to ask by example.

I'm parsing something like below (rectangle and text definitions in a PDF content):

```
---
---
85.039 42.52 42.519 42.52 re
W--
---
---
127.559 42.52 42.519 42.52 re
W--
---
---
170.078 42.52 42.52 42.52 re
W--
---
---
BT
---
Text
---
ET
---
---
170.078 42.52 42.52 42.52 re
W--
---
---
127.559 42.52 42.519 42.52 re
W--
---
---
BT
---
Text
---
ET
---
---
170.078 42.52 42.52 42.52 re
W--
---
---
BT
---
Text
---
ET
---
---
```

> **Dashes for example only**, in the real data dashes can be anything (various control characters / numerics / matrices / whatnot).

Currently I'm capturing these groups:

```
# Clipping Rectangle
(?<x>\b[-0-9\.]+\b)(\s)
(?<y>\b[-0-9\.]+\b)(\s)
(?<width>\b[-0-9\.]+\b)(\s)
(?<height>\b[-0-9\.]+\b)(\s)
(re\nW)

(.*?)

# Text
(BT)
(?<text>.*?)
(ET)
```

But in these matches, the first (furthest) clipping rectangle is captured instead of the last (closest).
How can I capture the closest clipping groups to the text groups **using Regex**?

I have this:
[image]

But I want this:
[image]

---

UPDATE: See on [**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/1myNXL/5/).

Comment: Perhaps use `([^\d]*)` instead of `(.*?)`? https://regex101.com/r/1myNXL/1/

Comment: @Nick Sorry to not pointing out, but dashes are for example only. Real data if full of various control characters between the ones I'm looking for. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a negative lookahead for the 4 numbers followed by `re\nW` after each character in the `.*?` match to exclude the pattern from occurring again before the match with the text:

```
# Clipping Rectangle
(?<x>\b[-0-9\.]+\b)(\s)
(?<y>\b[-0-9\.]+\b)(\s)
(?<width>\b[-0-9\.]+\b)(\s)
(?<height>\b[-0-9\.]+\b)(\s)
(re\nW)

((?:.(?!(\b[-\d.]+\b\s){4}re\nW))*?)

# Text
(BT)
(?<text>.*?)
(ET)
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1myNXL/6)

Comment: Thanks for getting back! Sorry for not pointing out, but the data have several groups/matches like this, and this negative lookahead only matches the very last. Could you help with the updated string [here](https://regex101.com/r/1myNXL/5)?

Comment: @Geri see my edit and updated demo. By moving the negative lookahead for the match to after each character in the text matching between the pattern and the `BT...ET` sequence, we can allow for multiple matches in the text. Note it does slow the code down a bit; if that's an issue you might want to consider using your original solution and then post-processing each of those matches with my original answer.

Comment: Thanks for your time @Nick, super useful answer! I have difficulties by understanding what the engine exactly does, but it works just the right way for sure!

Comment: @Geri no worries - I'm glad it was helpful.